# Laravel SammyK BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hi I follwed the basic example from https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk#user-login-from-redirect-example

and run into this **issue:**

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::createOrUpdateGraphNode()

I have no idea what this means and how to solve this. Can anybody help?

Comment: It means the createOrUpdateGraphNode() method can not be found like it says. Post your code so we can see more, this could be a multitude of things going wrong.